# Running homebrew while in a virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, homebrew

**Simple question**: is running homebrew while in a virtualenv a bad idea?

If so, is there any way that I can automatically deactivate the virtualenv each time I run a homebrew command? I don't trust myself to always remember to deactivate the virtualenv or open a new terminal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think if they are related. You have to use pip for python package management when you use virtualenv. this way you make sure that your new stuff is on the sandbox you created. AFAIK home-brew installs stuff globally. So better not use it to get the python modules. hope it helps.

Comment: OK, that's the plan, but running commands like `brew doctor` and then solving the issues while in a virtualenv is still ok?

Comment: yes, should be ok. They are fixed globally and have nothing to do with your sandbox. You can always use 'pip list' to see which libraries and which version u have. (if you are on a sandbox, it shows you stuff available to you in the sandbox)

Answer (score 5):

Since I just ran across this myself in the [documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#virtualenv), it's probably better in general **not** to `brew install` from within an active virtualenv.  To quote from said docs:

> WARNING: When you brew install formulae that provide Python bindings, you should not be in an active virtual environment.
>
> Activate the virtualenv after you've brewed, or brew in a fresh Terminal window. Homebrew will still install Python modules into Homebrew's site-packages and not into the virtual environment's site-package.
>
> Virtualenv has a switch to allow "global" (i.e. Homebrew's) site-packages to be accessible from within the virtualenv.

As such, if you are certain the formula you are brewing will not attempt to provide new Python bindings then let it rip.  But for me, if there's no specific reason to `brew install` with my virtual environment activated, I try and remember to `deactivate` beforehand.